# How to get a staggered grid view of text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm pulling books from an online api, however this api returns it as a list of sentences.
I want to display these sentences in containers and make it look like a normal paragraph yet every sentence is clickable.

**Expected result:**
With each being a separate container in order to be clickable

```
Sentence number one. This is
sentence number two. And
this is sentence number three.
This sentence 4. This is 
sentence number 5
```

I've tried to join the strings, and put them all in one Text widget, which looked like expected, but lost control over each sentence.
I've also tried to put each sentence in a Text widget, and wrap them with the Wrap() widget.

**Wrap widget result**

```
Sentence number 1. This is 2.
This is sentence number 3 and
it's long.
This is sentence number 4.
This is 5.
This is sentence number 6 and
its longer than all of them.
```

Its a step closer yet so far away, when the sentences are longer than the screens width it starts to look more like a listview, I'm trying to find a way to break these text widgets into two where it goes out of screen, instead of them taking 2 rows by default. I want to know if its possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<TextSpan> reasonList = [];
                  snapshot.data!.forEach((element) {
                    reasonList.add(TextSpan(text: '${element.sentence}'));
                  });
                  return Container(
                    child: RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                          children: reasonList,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16)),
                    ),
                  );
```